# TableColumn Bindings.createLongBinding Error(JAVAFX)

Tags: java, javafx, binding, tablecolumn

why does this code gives error. im trying to display in my tablecolumn the total of num1 and num2 values.

```
 tablecolumn1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        Person num = cellData.getValue();
        return Bindings.createLongBinding(() -> {
            try {
                        Long num1 = num.getnum1());
                        Long num2 = num.getnum2();
                        return num2 - num1 + 1;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0;
            }
        },
                num.getnum1(), num.getnum2()
        );
    });
```

this is my person Model.
    //Person Model

```
private SimpleLongProperty num1;
private SimpleLongProperty num2;

 public Person( Long num1, Long num2){
       this.num1= new SimpleLongProperty(num1);
       this.num2= new SimpleLongProperty(num2);}

    public Long getNum1() {
        return this.num1.get();
    }

    public void setNum1(Long num1) {
        this.num1.set(num1);
    }

    public Long getNum2() {
        return this.num2.get();
    }

    public void setNum2(Long num2) {
        this.num2.set(num2);
    }
```

Update: SOLUTION
never thought it was this easy. but hey we learn from our mistakes! ^_^

```
  tablecolumn1.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(
  String.valueOf(c.getValue().getnum1() - c.getValue().getnum2() + 1)));
```

Comment: sorry for the typo error. i  forgot to change them. it is now updated btw. please check. thanks

Comment: I'm still not sure where the `data` variable you're using comes from. May I assume that you're getting a compile time error. Also what's the compiler's message?

Comment: done doublechecking it sir.

Comment: The error should be on line `return 0;` instead (since `Long+Long-int` = `long`) and it's caused by java being unable to autobox a primitive `int` to `Long`. It can only do this for primitive `long`. In this case it should be simple to fix this using a long literal: `return 0L;`. Furthermore you should use primitive `long` in your `Person` class, since `SimpleLongProperty` replaces `null` with `0` anyways; it simply stores a primitive `long` value and the conversion to reference type `Long` costs resources and is may be confusing to someone reading the code...

Comment: Or just remove the try-catch block. The code you posted can't throw a `NumberFormatException` anyway.

Comment: Already done the return 0L but still gives me error